# Helm use default string when values is empty string

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

While using Helm3, I want to set certain name as `(.Values.nameOverride)-init` when `.Values.nameOverride` is set, and set the name as "init" when `.Values.nameOverride` isn't set (Just defined as empty string). However, by using the expression below, default is never used.

```
name: {{ printf "%s-init" .Values.nameOverride | default "init" }}
```

I can achieve what I'm trying to achieve, by using more lines.

```
  {{- if .Values.nameOverride }}
  name: {{ .Values.nameOverride }}-init
  {{- else }}
  name: "init"
  {{- end }}
```

Is it possible to achieve the goal in a more simple way? I have to use this expression in multiple places, so I want to shorten the expression.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Go `text/template`](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template) `with` operator is helpful here.  Like `if`, it tests to see if the value is "truthy"; if it is, then inside the block, it binds the special variable `.` to the value it matched.  So here you could write:

```yaml
name: {{ with .Values.nameOverride }}{{ . }}-{{ end }}init
```

Breaking this into more lines:

```yaml
name: {{/* comment */}}
{{- with .Values.nameOverride -}} {{-/* if the value is defined */-}}
  {{- . -}}                       {{-/* emit it */-}}
  -                               {{-/* and a hyphen */-}}
{{- end -}}
init                              {{-/* and either way, the string "init" */}}
```